# Checking mulitple rows in a count() function

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

Not sure if I am missing something simple (I have been working on this for awhile now). I am trying to make a simple appointment book and I have a simple table set up with timeslots in them

```
id timeslot montgomery birmingham
1   8-10    2        2
2   9-12    6        3
3   12-3    6        3
4   3-5     2        2
```

I have this as my controller

```
public function getSchedule() { 
    $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);   

    $input = [
        'date' => Input::get('date'),
        'timeslot' => Input::get('timeslot')
    ];                  

    $date = strtotime($input['date']);

    $dateFormat = date('Y-m-d',$date);

    $block = DB::table('bk_timeslot')
            ->where('id', '=', $input['timeslot'])
            ->first();      

    if($user->office == "Birmingham") {

        $count = Schedule::where('date', '=', $dateFormat)->count();

        $full = "Sorry Birmingham does not have an appointment open for this day";

        if ($count >= $block->birmingham) {
            return Redirect::to('book/schedule')->withErrors($full)->withInput();
        }   
    }   

    if($user->office == "Montgomery") {


        $count = Schedule::where('date', '=', $dateFormat)          
                ->count();

        var_dump($count); die;

        $full = "Sorry Montgomery does not have an appointment open for this day";

        if ($count >= $block->montgomery) {
            return Redirect::to('book/schedule')->withErrors($full)->withInput();
        }   
    }       

    //puts info in a session for later use
    Session::put('schedule', $input); 

    return Redirect::to('book/review');
}
```

All works well except this line:

```
$count = Schedule::where('date', '=', $dateFormat)->count();
```

what it's doing is counting the ENTIRE day and not checking if the timeslot is also taking:

**Structure of schedule table**

```
id   date   timeslot
1   2013-10-11  1
1   2013-10-11  1
1   2013-10-11  4
```

So if you attempt to book a timeslot of 8-10 on 10-11 you won't beable to because its full..that's fine but you also cannot book a 3-5 because that's id as 2 also. How can i check BOTH and move on from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a second `where` clause:

```
$count = Schedule::where('date', '=', $dateFormat)
         ->where('timeslot', '=', $block->id)
         ->count();
```

You can use `$input['timeslot']` instead of `$block->id` (they are supposed to be the same).

Comment: Thanks you J. It must be because I have been lacking sleep building this. lol thanks you for you quick response!!